# XSLT - To move parent attribute value into child first para

Tags: xslt

Input is like as,

```
<section counter="yes" level="5">
<title><target id="page92"/></title>
<section counter="yes" level="6">
<title>Standard 12-lead ECG at Rest</title>
<para>The standard ECG is recorded at rest using 12 leads in order to collect as much information as possible:</para>
<listing type="dash">
<litem><para>Standard limb leads according to Einthoven (I, II, III)</para></litem>
```

Output should be,

```
    <section counter="yes" level="5">
    <title><target /></title>
    <section counter="yes" level="6">
    <title>Standard 12-lead ECG at Rest</title>
    <para id="page92">The standard ECG is recorded at rest using 12 leads in order to collect as much information as possible:</para>
    <listing type="dash">
    <litem><para>Standard limb leads according to Einthoven (I, II, III)</para></litem>
```

We wrote xslt as shown below,

```
<xsl:template match="para[1][parent::section[parent::section[not(normalize-space(title))]]]">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
            <para>
                <xsl:attribute name="id" select="ancestor::section[not(normalize-space(title))]/title/target/@id"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </para>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <para>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </para>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

While using above xslt, we are unable to meet expected output.

```
    <section counter="yes" level="5">
    <title><target /></title>
    <section counter="yes" level="6">
    <title>Standard 12-lead ECG at Rest</title>
    <para id="page92">The standard ECG is recorded at rest using 12 leads in order to collect as much information as possible:</para>
    <listing type="dash">
    <litem><para id="page92">Standard limb leads according to Einthoven (I, II, III)</para></litem>
```

The "page ID" value is repeating on following paragraphs which we didn't required. We need to maintain the page ID only on 1st paragraph.

Could you please guide us.

Comment: I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete samples to allow others to reproduce the problem. It would also help if you indent your XML to allow us to grasp the structure. When I try to reproduce the problem at http://xsltransform.net/a9GixP I don't see the result you say you get so it is not clear to me why that code you posted would create the result you say you get.

Answer (score 0):

As for getting the result you want, it should be as simple as

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section[not(normalize-space(title))]/section/para[1]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="id" select="ancestor::section[not(normalize-space(title))]/title/target/@id"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section/title[not(normalize-space())]/target/@id"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thanku for your response Martin. I am tried your XSLT but it's replacing "id" into all para at same "section" level. Which means, replacing the same para id into all section "level="6".

Comment: Please edit your question and show the relevant input. If you only want to transform the first `para` in the first `section` you could change the match pattern to `section[not(normalize-space(title))]/section[1]/para[1]` easily.